# What is the smallest way to store a UUID that is human readable?

Tags: sql, database, language-agnostic, guid, uuid

What is the smallest way to store a UUID that is human readable and widely database compatible?

I am thinking a char array of some sort using hex values?

Comment: If this is a question for a specific case, then: are you sure you need the Universal uniqueness?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As common approach, i think that encoding the binary data (16 bytes) as Base64 could be what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Base-85](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base-85) encoding to store the UUID as 20 US-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the latest podcast relevant:

http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/shows/detail4087.html

[Database-wide unique-yet-simple identifiers in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721497/database-wide-unique-yet-simple-identifiers-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You want Base64 if it is going to be in any kind of computer representation. Base85 if you can figure out a way around putting it in a URL. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85