# Can I get shorter UUIDs in RethinkDB?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

Is there a way to get shorter unique IDs for entries in RethinkDB?

We have a URL scheme where `<url>/:ID` URLs get very long with the default ID

Their docs don't seem to talk about this... 
https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/uuid/

Answer (score 1):

According to the linked documentation, we should read Wikipedia's article for UUID. Which starts said article with: *A universally unique identifier (UUID) is a 128-bit number [...]*. So I guess that no: UUID is a fixed-length thing. (Yeah, I learnt something too here.)

Answer (score 0):

RethinkDB will by default use uuid as `id` . If you want a shorter id, handle it from your application side. Before inserting set `id` value. Be careful with your id generation logic, if it conflicts with existing ids in your table, it will overwrite them.

Comment: This seemed like a good discussion on the topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564112/is-it-safe-to-turn-a-uuid-into-a-short-code-only-use-first-8-chars