# flask upload grayscale image

Tags: python, flask

i'm studying flask. when i select an image file, i want to convert that image grayscale by cv2. but `cv2.imread` can't read variable . i make new function or add some code line? i think there is nothing to change in html
app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for,send_from_directory
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os

FOLDER_PATH = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\teran\\Desktop\\Ps_Sd\\uploads\\')
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set([ 'png','PNG', 'jpg', 'jpeg'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = FOLDER_PATH

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
            filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))
    return render_template('upload.html')
  
@app.route('/show/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    filename = 'http://localhost:5000/uploads/' + filename
    return render_template('upload.html', filename=filename)

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def send_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(FOLDER_PATH, filename)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of the `cv2.imdecode` function as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34475270/2052575) then use `c2.imencode` to get it back to a writable stream.

So I would make a function to create the grayscale image like:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def make_grayscale(in_stream):
    # Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34475270

    #use numpy to construct an array from the bytes
    arr = np.fromstring(in_stream, dtype='uint8')

    #decode the array into an image
    img = cv2.imdecode(arr, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    # Make grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    _, out_stream = cv2.imencode('.PNG', gray)

    return out_stream
```

Then if you wanted to change that image to grayscale on upload (saving it on your server in grayscale) you could modify the upload code to look more like:

```
# ...
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file_data = make_grayscale(file.read())

            with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename),
                      'wb') as f:
                f.write(file_data)

            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))
# ...
```

On a side note, you should probably be aware that using the originally uploaded filename to name the file can lead to later problems, which I've covered in another answer regarding [handling duplicate filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61535724/2052575).