# how can I make a upload file in flask

Tags: python, flask, file-upload

This is my upload function but every time I go to `addclothes` route and adding image into the form then I got this error:
[image: this is the error]

I know is my path problem but I don't know how to put the file in the base directory

```py
@app.route('/addclothes', methods=["POST","GET"])
def addclothes():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']

        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file :
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join('/static/img/',filename))

            new_clothes = Clothes(clothesname=clothesname,image=image,price=price,isSuperUser=False)
            db.session.add(new_clother)
            db.session.commit()
            
            return redirect(url_for('addclothes'))



    return render_template('addclothes.html')
```

This is my file structure:

[image: file structure]

I want to add it to base directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save this with:

```
file.save(os.path.join('static/img/',filename))
```

Note the removal of the preceding `/` before static.  With this present it is trying to save to a `static` subdirectory on the `/` drive of the *server*, not within the app's directory.

On a side note, it may be to your advantage to make a filename containing random characters, rather than using the user-provided filename; certainly if you're handling a large number of file uploads.  See another thread I wrote regarding [avoiding duplicate filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61534027/how-should-i-handle-duplicate-filenames-when-uploading-a-file-with-flask/61535724#61535724).

Comment: Thanks you so much It helps me a lot. You save my life(This question have border me a whole day!!!).

Comment: @KennethLau No problem. If this solved your issue, please consider marking the answer as accepted.