# Comparing UUIDs in Java

Tags: java, hash, uuid

Do UUID in Java for String objects will be the same if those strings are equal? If not, Is there a way/tool to generate string (with proper UUID format) that will stay the same if will be computed on equal string? I need some kind of hash for string, that keep UUID format. Is there something like this in Java?

[Edit]:
You will propably ask what exacly I am trying to do. I am making a part of application that will translate object from one servis to another. One of those servises indentity object by UUID. Second one do not store it. I do not want to cach whole data of those services, so I have to generate that UUID somehow.

Comment: Are you wanting a name-based UUID? That will work if you use a standard character set to convert the `String` to `byte[]` (I'm doing this now and use UTF-8).

Comment: Err, a UUID is not a hash...

Comment: Similar question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804591/efficient-method-to-generate-uuid-string-in-java-uuid-randomuuid-tostring-w

Comment: I don't understand "I need some kind of hash for string, that keep UUID format." Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

> Do UUID in Java for String objects will be the same if those strings are equal?

No, since this prints false:

```
final String s = "Mémé dans les orties ";
final UUID uuid1 = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
final UUID uuid2 = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE));
System.out.println(uuid1.equals(uuid2));
```

You need to encode the `String` into a byte array and use the *same encoding* on both sides.

---

What is more, a UUID is not a hash per se; if you want hashes like sha1, sha256 etc, have a look at Guava

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");  
    md.update("test".getBytes());
    byte[] a = md.digest();     // 16 bytes for MD5
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(a);
    long l1 = bb.getLong();
    long l2 = bb.getLong();
    UUID uuid = new UUID(l1, l2);
    System.out.println(uuid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You just have to use `UUID.fromString()` with the result of `uuid.toString()`:

```
UUID id1 = UUID.randomUUID();
String s = id1.toString();
UUID id2 = UUID.fromString(s);

assertTrue(id1, id2);
```