# How to send email with registration link for confirmation of new user using JSP and servlet?

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, servlets

I am doing a project where I want a mail to be sent to a new user with a link for confirmation and after clicking that link then only he can access his profile. 
After many types of research, I am unable to find a proper answer on how to implement this in my project.
I am using JSP and servlet for development in localhost. I hope here I will get the proper solution for my problem.

Comment: check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545507/how-to-verify-user-clicked-on-link-in-email-that-i-sent-him-her

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is too broad.. In order to achieve your requirement we need to do multiple things

> 1. Need smtp server
> 2. Send Email though Java using smtp
> 3. generate a unique key, encrypt it and add it to registration link (http://www.myxyz.com?sId=XXXXXXXXXXX) and save non-encrypted key in database (you need some kind of cross verification process)
> 4. when user clicks link, grab the key and decrypt it and validate the key with key in database

In order to achieve item-2 follow http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-email-using-java-mail-api

I used following way to generate unique key (item-3)[Efficient method to generate UUID String in JAVA (UUID.randomUUID().toString() without the dashes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804591/efficient-method-to-generate-uuid-string-in-java-uuid-randomuuid-tostring-w)

item-4: Implement logic on server side (Servlet is best option)

Comment: Do I have to create a new table for storing key related to confirmation?
I have a contact form and also option to reset password. 
To implement this feature I need to send an email by Gmail server or any other way is also there?
Studying about sending email by Gmail server: http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-email-using-java-mail-api-through-gmail-server

Comment: I have similar kind of application, i'm storing key in Database so that i could set expiration for each key.

Comment: Have you used Gmail server for sending mail?

Comment: @Dinesh I used my own smtp.

Comment: Have you shared your project in Github?
I just want to have a look on how you implemented

Comment: @Dinesh I cannot share Code.. I shared my approach though answer.. If this solves your question then please accept answer.

Comment: what will be the attributes of the table that will store the key?

Comment: Better to have a table with userId , Unique key, email sent time, verified email time, email status.. Again it completely dpends on your application.

Comment: @Dinesh if this is your expected answer for your question,,please accept the answer so that this question won't appear as unanswered.