# Attribute Value to set with unique number

Tags: java, xml, spring, validation, uniqueidentifier

I am using this method to create random numbers Adding to element value in xml in another method. some files that are same won't compare. because numbers I am inserting are random not unique anymore. How to insert same number if file1name equals file1name. else random numbers.

```
Random random = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (arrayList.size() < 6) {
        int a = random.nextInt(49)+1; 

        if (!arrayList.contains(a)) {
            arrayList.add(a);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance! new still a lot to learn.

Comment: A unique number may be something like `System.currentTimeMillis()` unless it is a busy multi-threaded system.

Comment: good one. I also thought about that actually. but not feasible in my case. hundred of files compared at a time.

Comment: Maybe create a singleton who's sole function is to provide you with these numbers.  Maybe utilize a `ArrayBlockingQueue`

Comment: Rather than an integer, a [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html) generated by `UUID.randomUUID()` might suit your needs.  See [How good is Java's UUID.randomUUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2513573/3744182) and maybe [Efficient method to generate UUID String in JAVA (UUID.randomUUID().toString() without the dashes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3804591).