# How to convert two longs to a byte array = how to convert UUID to byte array?

Tags: java, arrays, uuid, long-integer

I am using Javas `UUID` and need to convert a UUID to a byte Array. Strangely the UUID Class does not provide a `"toBytes()"` method.

I already found out about the two methods:

```
UUID.getMostSignificantBits()
and
UUID.getLeasSignificantBits()
```

But how to get this into a byte array? the result should be a byte[] with those tow values. I somehow need to do Bitshifting but, how?

**update:**

I found:

```
 ByteBuffer byteBuffer = MappedByteBuffer.allocate(2);
 byteBuffer.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
 byteBuffer.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
```

Is this approach corret?

Are there any other methods (for learning purposes)?

Thanks very much!!
Jens

Comment: The code in the update is not correct: it only allocates two bytes in the buffer but you need 16. The code in the answer below is however correct.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use ByteBuffer

```
 byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
 ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
 bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN or ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
 bb.putLong(UUID.getMostSignificantBits());
 bb.putLong(UUID.getLeastSignificantBits());

 // to reverse
 bb.flip();
 UUID uuid = new UUID(bb.getLong(), bb.getLong());
```

Answer (score 5):

One option if you prefer "regular" IO to NIO:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
dos.write(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
dos.write(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
dos.flush(); // May not be necessary
byte[] data = dos.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

### For anyone trying to use this in Java 1.7, I found the following to be necessary:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
dos.writeLong(password.getMostSignificantBits());
dos.writeLong(password.getLeastSignificantBits());
dos.flush(); // May not be necessary
return baos.toByteArray();
```