# Alternative for UUID

Tags: javascript, random, uuid

I am using `UUID`to generate random codes. But It's returning me 20+ digits. Is there is any other algorithm mechanism that returns 8-digit code that is unique or any other way to reduce UUID code length.

**Code**

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
uuidv4(); // ⇨ '1b9d6bcd-bbfd-4b2d-9b5d-ab8dfbbd4bed'
```

Comment: I use UniqID, to generate 8 and 12 bits longs ids https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniqid

Comment: 8 and 12 bits? that's gonna run out quick :p

Comment: You do understand the chance of "collision" using only 32 bits it far greater than when using the 128 bits (ok, a few less) of a UUID?

Comment: if the UUID generation is not too quick(like in milliseconds) you can use timestamp `+new Date()`

Comment: An uuid contains 32 hex characters, thats 128bit of data. A String character can contain 16bit of data. So, let's format that differently: `'1b9d6bcd-bbfd-4b2d-9b5d-ab8dfbbd4bed'.replace(/\W+/g, "").replace(/..../g, m => String.fromCharCode("0x"+m))` makes exactly 8 characters, still contains 128bit of data

Answer (score 9):

You could try nanoid out.

It's smaller in size compared to UUID, faster and generates shorter unique codes.

```js
    import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
    model.id = nanoid() //=> "V1StGXR8_Z5jdHi6B-myT"
```

Read more of it here:
https://github.com/ai/nanoid

Answer (score 4):

For random strings of any size, as well as applications that need "stronger" random strings/numbers, you can use the `crypto` module.

For example, if you want 8 hexadecimal characters (= 4 bytes), you could use

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

var randomHexString = crypto.randomBytes(4).toString("hex");
```

you can use other characters sets too, for example if you want 8 random Base 64 characters (= 6 bytes):

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

var randomB64String = crypto.randomBytes(6).toString("base64");
```

Answer (score 3):

For v4 UUIDs, those first 4 bytes are random.  So, if you wanted, you could take the first 4 bytes (8 characters of hexadecimal), and use them as-is.

Keep in mind though that the UUID is designed to avoid collisions.  If you too want to avoid collisions, you should just use UUID as-is.

Another way to reduce its character length is to use some other encoding rather than hexadecimal.  You could use Base-64, for example.  See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15013205/362536

Answer (score 2):

You can try ULID. It is a `Universally Unique Lexicographically Sortable Identifier`.

- [ULID spec](https://github.com/ulid/spec)
- [Javascript package](https://github.com/ulid/javascript)