# How to create a unique order number

Tags: algorithm, database-design, uniqueidentifier

Algorithmically speaking, how could I generate a unique, human readable, reasonably lengthed - order number for SQL Server column.  The only requirement is that it references the Customer Number and can be easily repeated over the phone.

Something like:

- Customer Number - XXXXXXXX - XXXXXXXX

RT65-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX

How would I generate the XXXXXXXX?  (Use random alpha-numeric data and then checking to see if it was in fact a duplicate?)

*and*

What are the best methods/considerations when generating these types of numbers?

How have you done this in your application?

Comment: Can it be a hash or does the order number have to correlate with the customer? I know when I do my banking, my confirmation number follows a convention: numerical month, numerical day, time in hours, time in minutes. As an example, it would be 1271259

Answer (score 2):

Use an identity column and pad with zeros.

Alter the start and increment values to taste.

Optionally, add a CRC check digit.

Comment: For a check digit, I've always been a fan of making the number a multiple of 11. The most common data entry error is digit reversal, followed by wrong digit. Both of those errors always change the value of a number mod 11.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these posts, nearly the exact same question.  Real good data in both (I've used them before):

[A good algorithm for generating an order number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823864/a-good-algorithm-for-generating-an-order-number)

[What is the best format for a customer number, order number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178572/what-is-the-best-format-for-a-customer-number-order-number)

Answer (score 0):

This is silly but fairly straight forward,
How about 
 yyyymmddhhmmss

and use it with

RT65-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX

Answer (score 0):

in php you can do like the following:

```
<?php 
$stamp = strtotime("now");
$orderid = 'RT65-'.$stamp.'-'.$REMOTE_ADDR; 
$orderid = str_replace(".", "", $orderid); 
echo($orderid); 
?>
```